# Is it colloquially acceptable to use ETA in place of "estimated time to completion"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english, abbreviations, colloquialisms

Literally, ETA means "estimated time to arrival". It is often used when traveling, like you want to know your ETA to your destination, or the ETA for the package delivery.

However, often I find myself wanting to use ETA when I am referring to a completion date, even though literally ETA means arrival, not completion. Obviously, there is no colloquial expression, "ETC", especially since that could be confused with "et cetera" in writing.

I wanted to know what you people think about this, is it colloquially acceptable to use ETA in place of "estimated time to completion"? I do believe the other party would understand, but I am more concerned with proper grammatical usage.

Comment: Define *acceptable* and *colloquially acceptable*. Primarily opinion-based. Most AmE speakers will understand you, at least. Dunno about other English speakers.

Comment: I like it.  However, you will have to define it at least several times per recipient.  Eventually, everyone in your circle will know what you mean, and it may even catch on.  Don't use it with people you don't know well enough to know how they will react.

Comment: Colloquial and “proper grammatical usage” don’t really go together.

Comment: @Jim: True, I suppose I am asking two questions: whether it is colloquially acceptable, and whether it is grammatically acceptable. Also, a third question: whether it is colloquially grammatically acceptable. If so, then a fourth: whether it is universally colloquially grammatically acceptable among American English speakers irrespective of geographic region, or only regionally colloquially grammatically acceptable.

Comment: @ab: I have used it before and it can be contextually discerned by the listener without any explanation necessary.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, at least in the hi-tech and software development industry. This phrase/acronym is used for the date of task completion.

See, for example, this forum question:

[ETA on fixing the underlying issue](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/44225697/eta-on-fixing-the-underlying-issue)

Comment: hard choice between yours and the one below.

Comment: @user7783780 - glad to see i helped :)

Answer (score 11):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimated_time_of_arrival) describes this usage:

> **ETA is also used metaphorically in situations where nothing actually moves physically, as in describing the time estimated for a certain task to complete** (e.g. work undertaken by an individual; a computation undertaken by a computer program; or a process undertaken by an organization). **The associated term is "estimated time of accomplishment", which may be a backronym.**[citation needed] For example, Bittorrent clients specify ETA as the expected time remaining for a file to completely download as 1d4h (1 day and 4 hours), 1w2d (1 week and 2 days), etc.

I personally use and hear it in this way quite a lot, and it's quite common to see in technologic applications in terms of down/uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

A common expression (AmE) for the expected date for completion of a project,delivery of product or a report (and the like) is: "Drop Dead Date".

As in: "I see your company is trying to have the new golf course operational by this spring - what's your ***Drop Dead Date***?"

Comment: That's an interesting phrase. I've personally heard "ETA" used in OP's context, but never heard of "Drop Dead Date" until your comment!

Comment: I have heard drop dead date as the date something absolutely  needs to be ready for, but never heard it for the estimated time of completion. Usually  I hear the two  contrasted - the ETA is Wednesday but the DDD is Friday means that we expect to complete on Wednesday but, if it is delayed until Friday it wouldn't really matter. I am UK-based.

Answer (score 0):

I have often seen **ECD** on a project matrix: Estimated Completion Date.

[Humphreys Association:](https://www.humphreys-assoc.com/evms/estimate-completion-project-management-best-practice-ta-a-85.html)

> Project managers are continually asked ... that the project’s cost and schedule goals can be met within the authorized budget ...  The Estimated at Completion (EAC) and the Estimated Completion Date (ECD) are the measures used to provide the answers to this question.

Casually, ETA sounds fine, but the hour is important at a airline or train station, more than to a project task measure in *days*.